# Objects are being overwritten when pushing in AngularJs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, arrays

everyone. Using angularjs 1.2v. I have an array in model. The page is quite big so I will try to describe it shortly.

```
    $scope.model={
      salary,
      position,
      user:
      [{
      name:'',
      address:''
      }]
    }
```

And functions to add items into that array:

```
$scope.submitFunc = function(item){
  $model.user.push(item);
}
```

And this is html file:

```
<div class="panel panel-success" ng-repeat="item in model.user">
   <div class="form-group">
     <label>NameLabel</label>
     <input ng-model="item.name" type = text />  
   </div>
   <div class="form-group">
     <label>addressLabel</label>
     <input ng-model="item.address" type = text />
   </div>
   <button ng-click="submitFunc(item)">Submit<>
</div>
```

After clicking button I need my array in model to look like this:

```
$scope.model={
 'salary': 'some value',
 'position': 'some value',
 'user':[{name: 'value', address:'value2'},
{name: 'value3', address:'value4'},
... ]
}
```

How to construct Submit function correct it to add new values not just rewrite them? Purpose of this is a form which user is able to fill out random amount of times. And on button click data should go to array and fields should be cleared... Thank you !

Comment: In your example, you are iterating over the array and generating a new form for each item. If this is what you actually have that will need to be corrected first. Unless that is your intention. From your description it seems you want to add to the array.

Comment: did you checked my answer ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Try this it will work :**

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

myApp.controller('MyCtrl',function ($scope) {
    $scope.model={
      salary:'',
      position:'',
      user:
      [{
      name:'',
      address:''
      }]
    }
    $scope.submitFunc = function(item){
      $scope.model.user.push(angular.copy(item));
      $scope.model.user.pop(angular.copy(item));
      $scope.model.user.push({
      name:'',
      address:''
      });
      console.log($scope.model);
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  <div class="panel panel-success" ng-repeat="item in model.user">
   <div class="form-group">
     <label>NameLabel</label>
     <input ng-model="item.name" type = text />  
   </div>
   <div class="form-group">
     <label>addressLabel</label>
     <input ng-model="item.address" type = text />
   </div>
   <button ng-click="submitFunc(item)">Submit</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you! Can you give some advice how to clear fields after Submit done? It will not work correct  if to assign item to null

Comment: @OlegIaremchuk I updated the answer as per your request. Please check now it will work as per your expectation.

Answer (score 1):

You need to copy the object. You are passing a reference:

```
angular.copy(source);
```

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.copy

```
$scope.submitFunc = function(item){
  $model.user.push(angular.copy(item));
}
```

Comment: It does the trick. Thank you! Just need to change to $scope.model.user ... But on click it is opening the form again. How to realize it to clear the form and does not open the new one?